# Differences Omron ST and Siemens SCL

Tags: logic, plc

What are the differences between Omron ST-Language and Siemens S7 SCL (definition of variables, the editor, syntax)?
*I know they both claim to be standardized by IEC 61131-3.*

What Omron programming suites are there and is a structured language supported?

Comment: As per the standard, 61131-compliant systems are to be supplied with compliance tables of all supported, unsupported and implementation-dependent features. For Siemens, it's the "Standards Compliance according to IEC 61131-3" document (you can google the PDF version of it). Unfortunately, I couldn't find the same kind of info for Omron.

Answer (score 0):

SCL (Structured Control Language) seems to be Siemens' version of Structured Text. So potentially there are a few differences but the overall concept and features will be the same.

In terms of programming for **OMRON PLCs**, there's **[Sysmac](http://industrial.omron.co.uk/en/products/catalogue/automation_systems/machine_automation_controllers/software/sysmac_studio/default.html)**, which supports Structured Text and Ladder Diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

They both belong to structural programming languages for PLC, just the company technology is different, For Siemens ST represented by SCL(structural control language), From my experience both programming languages are inherited from C_ programming language, and for better understanding the best is to go to Siemens's forums as well as Omron's forums they provide more detailed and accurate information.

Comment: I see this is your first post, thank you for your answer. While you have included some material here, the summary of your answer is to read some other material. Answers should be complete in themselves rather than be a link to other material, though it is ok to use links to reference your own answer.